# iOS Python WebDriver - WebDriverException: Message: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.querySelectorAll')

Tags: python, ios, selenium

I'm using appium (v1.4.5 (REV 9d1af07681e73c01d59eca608b9ca57c97e9b4dc)) along with selenium's python bindings to automate Mobile Safari on the simulator and a real device.

In the simulator:
I'm able to get to a certain point in the test, until I have to switch iframes to access elements. Once I either attempt to switch frames, or attempt to click an element, I'm met with the above error.

I've searched, but could not find anything relative to this - seems it's mostly encountered for those working with hybrid apps trying to switch back to WebView.
I'm only working with mobile safari.

Basically, I switch to the frame, then attempt a .click() on an element:

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, text))).click()

This is when the error is thrown. If I do any kind of find_element_by, the error is thrown. I've checked and double-checked I'm in the right frame, but still the error is there. Does anyone have an idea what's going on here? Please let me know if there's more info needed.

Comment: To add to this, I've also tried using .tap() methods without luck.

Comment: iOS 8.3

appium 1.4.5

xcode 6.3